# How do I do an exact word match on a variable in ksh?

Tags: perl, ksh

I used the following syntax as part of a ksh script to verify if the word `Validation` exists in `LINE_FROM_FILE`.

```
[[ "${LINE_FROM_FILE##*Validation}" != "${LINE_FROM_FILE}" ]] && print "match Validation"
```

The problem of this syntax is that it is also matching words like `Valid` or `ValidationVALID` etc. and my goal is to exactly match the word `Validation` in the variable `$LINE_FROM_FILE`.

I ask if it is also possible to use Perl syntax in my script to exactly match the word `Validation`, for example:

```
[[ ` some perl command ` = Validation  ]] && print "match Validation"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test whether the line contains the word between word-separating characters. A helpful trick is to add a word-separating character at the beginning and at the end of the string, in case the word is at the beginning or end of the string.

```
[[ " $LINE_FROM_FILE " == *[![:alnum:]]Validation[![:alnum:]]* ]]
```

This assumes that words consist of letters and digits only. Adjust the pattern if you have a different definition.

Note that the test you wrote, `[[ "${LINE_FROM_FILE##*Validation}" != "${LINE_FROM_FILE}" ]]`, is a complicated way of writing `[[ $LINE_FROM_FILE = *Validation* ]]` (i.e., checking for `Validation` as a substring).

Answer (score 0):

if your using bash, you're in luck:

[bash regexs](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/chap_04.html)

Example:

```
input=$1


if [[ "$input" =~ "[0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]" ]]
#                 ^ NOTE: Quoting not necessary, as of version 3.2 of Bash.
# NNN-NN-NNNN (where each N is a digit).
then
  echo "Social Security number."
  # Process SSN.
else
  echo "Not a Social Security number!"
  # Or, ask for corrected input.
fi
```

Comment: did you have relevant example to match Validation word