# perl + test perl syntax in my shell script (ksh)

Tags: perl

I used the following syntax (part of ksh script) to verify if Validation word exist in LINE_FROM_FILE

```
    [[ "${LINE_FROM_FILE##*Validation}" != "${LINE_FROM_FILE}" ]] && print "match Validation"
```

the problem of this sytax that its also match word like Valid or ValidationVALID etc

and my target to match exactly the Validation word in the $LINE_FROM_FILE

I ask if its also possible to use perl syntax in my script to match exactly the Validation word

for example

```
   [[ ` some perl command ` = Validation  ]] && print "match Validation"
```

Lidia

Comment: Isn't this a question for Stack Overflow?

Comment: I dont get answer from Stack Overflow

Comment: @lidia: [Your Stack Overflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3565283/how-do-i-do-an-exact-word-match-on-a-variable-in-ksh) has had answers. Give people more than 15 minutes to answer!

Answer (score 0):

yes.  `perl -e "insert; perl; code; here;"`

e.g.: `perl -e "print 'Validation'"`